# EGit spams git repository with typechanges

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit, git-clone, git-revert

I am using Eclipse Egit on Suse 11.0 with git version 1.8.0.1. Egit: 2.1.0

When I am cloning a repository from gerrit in Egit, I see a lot of typechanges in />git status
...
typechange: src/TestPorts/TELNET/XXX.xxx
...

and viewing the content of the file with command less:

../../../TestPorts/TELNET/XXX.xxx
~
~
~
~
~
~
~

So when I revert these changes with git reset --hard, I get unstaged chages in Egit. The unstaged files are the same as were in git status.
And when I revert those files with Eclipse, the issue starts again in git.

Any experiences regarding to this? thanks

Comment: You are sure, that it comes from `Egit` and not Eclipse itself, or any plugin (for example during an implicit build/during indexing)?

Comment: to be honest, I really dont know I just wrote what I use, and what is the experience

Answer (score 1):

This will be JGit bug, since I realised that these files are actualy symlincs. And somehow JGit can not resolve them correctly
see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354367